# Rails ajax return model no-db field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app is built on Rails 4.
I have a model `mem` which contains a custom field `realname`:

```
class Mem < ActiveRecord::Base
    def realname
       'hello' 
    end
end
```

Now,I post a ajax request form client to get the mems list,include the  field `realname`:

```
def
   render json: {Mem.all}
end
```

But the returned data didn't include  `realname`,why? and how I can realize this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a single model or a collection through, it uses `to_json` to format it. By default, this will grab its database attributes only. You can tell it to grab other data by doing this:

```
render json: Mem.all.to_json(methods: :realname)
```

Can read more up on how to use this method here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json. The linked method is deprecated, but the options are the same.